# "Resource shrinker cannot be used for libraries.", Gradle 3.0.1+

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**EDIT:** I did not need to use resource shrinker on this project, so simply removing the line dealt with my issue. Anyone seeing this should refer to the linked question for discussion of this bug, seems like for most people it was/will be fixed with the 3.2 release of Android Studio.

Having a problem using resourceShrinker on a library with the Android Plugin for Gradle, on any version more recent than 3.0.0. Seen in another answer than this is also a bug in Instant Apps for Android Studio fixed in 3.2+, but that doesn't seem fully relevant to my issue here, as I am not using Android Studio. Wondering if anyone else has come across this and if they had a solution? Thanks!

Snippet from the build.gradle file of the module in question:

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.3" 
        release {
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Facing same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: @shaby As per my edit I ended up removing the shrinkResources call from my gradle file as it was not necessary; but the linked duplicate question may have some helpful information for you!